# (RUBY) How to read HTML tag contents and print them in the console

Tags: html, ruby, tags

I stated messing with Ruby 3 days ago and I want to find the contents of a  tag

This is the code I got so far. Can someone please help?

```
    require 'open-uri'

print "Enter a website domain you like (without the http://): "
website = gets.chomp

if website.count(".") >= 2
  first_letter = website.index(".") + 1 # we want the letter just after the first dot
  after_first_letter = first_letter + 1
  last_letter = (website.index(".", after_first_letter) - 1)
  website_title = website[first_letter..last_letter]
elsif website.count(".") == 1
  website_title = website[0..(website.index(".") - 1)]
else
  website_title = nil
end

unless website_title.nil?
  file = open("http://#{website}")
  contents = file.read
  title = contents.index("<h3>")

  p "This is the title: #{title}"
  else
  puts "We aren't sure what you did. Try again..."
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nokogiri` to parse html. Run `gem install nokogiri`.

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://#{website}"))

html.css('h3').each do |title_node|
  puts "Title: #{title_node.content}"
end
```